How to prevent headlessui/react float from closing when clicking outside of it?
In headlessui/react float, when the menu is opened, what is the way to prevent it from closing when you click outside it?
<Menu>
  <Float show={show}>
    <Menu.Button onClick={toggle}>
      Options
    </Menu.Button>

    <Menu.Items static>
      ...
    </Menu.Items>
  </Float>
</Menu>

